# Installing ethernet device under LynxOS

Tags: drivers, unix

I changed my hard drive which was running LynxOS to another computer with diferent processor/mother board but same periphericals configuration. Everything is working except the network ethernet card. Leds are blinking properly and I reinstalled the drivers and build the kernel but it doesnt create the device when rebooting.

The only network devices I can see with the comand netstat -i are sl0 - 7 and lo0.

The network card is a PMC661J and the device should be rmx0.

Is there anyway I can see if the card is recognized by the system and why is not being related with the driver?

The LynxOS version is 3.0.0, but if you know how to do it in other Unix Systems please tell me and I will try it.

Thanks,
Zits

Comment: Rather than add [solved] to your question title it's better to accept your own answer. As well as telling visitors that the problem's solved, it also tells the system so the question won't get bumped to the home page - like it has done today.

Comment: Time to create a new OS tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had to configure on BIOS an IRQ for the PCI port in which the card was inserted.
Thanks for your guidance Stef

Answer (score 2):

Either  you  did  not  included  the correct  netwook  driver  in  kernel
see  (CONFIG.TBL)
either  the  device instalation did  not  detected  your  PMC  PCI  chipset

the  interface  will  be crreated  only  by  the  device driver once  device installation
succeed

look  at  the  devices  command  output  it  will tell  you  which  devices  have  been  configured  in kernel  and  tell you  the  one  that  failed  to be  initialised.

I  do  not  remember  which  chipset  was in  the  Ramix PMC661J
the  rmx0  interface  name leads  me  to  think  the  driver  fort  this  PMC  was  provided  by  ramix  (now  GEfanuc)

Cheers
Stef

Comment: And in my reponse I forgot to say that the chipset of the card is DEC 21041. You are right is a GEfanuc card.

Comment: Good answer stef, it solved my network-related problem in LynxOS.

Answer (score 1):

Thanxs for answering Stef.

As far as the line **I:pmc66x.cfg** is included on file **CONFIG.TBL** and not commented and that the file **pmc66x.cfg** is under directory **/sys/cfg** I would say it is not problem of the driver but of the PMC PCI chipset.

The output of the device command are the following lines

```
 id type  driver     use count start    size  name                            
 0  char  0          2         0        0     null device
 1  char  1          1         0        0     memory
 2  char  2          0         0        0     ctrl dev
 3  char  3          14        db15cde8 0     kdconsole
 4  char  4          0         db1600a0 0     com 1
 5  char  4          0         db160c88 0     com 2
 6  char  5          0         db161870 0     raw HD 0-1
 7  char  7          0         db163918 0     raw Floppy 0-3
 8  char  9          0         (no dev) 0     SIM1522 RAW SCSI
 9  char  11         0         (no dev) 0     SIM1542 RAW SCSI
 10 char  13         0         (no dev) 0     SIM1742 RAW SCSI
 11 char  15         0         (no dev) 0     SIM2742 RAW SCSI
 12 char  17         0         (no dev) 0     SIM2940 RAW SCSI
 13 char  19         0         (no dev) 0     Lowlevel SCSI
 14 char  20         0         db163e58 0     raw_scsi_hd
 15 char  22         0         db165408 0     raw_scsi_mt
 16 char  23         0         (no dev) 0     raw HDS 2-3
 17 char  25         5         db1657f0 0     pty 0
 18 char  25         0         db1663c0 0     pty 1
 19 char  25         0         db166f90 0     pty 2
 20 char  25         0         db167b60 0     pty 3
 21 char  25         0         db168730 0     pty 4
 22 char  25         0         db169300 0     pty 5
 23 char  25         0         db169ed0 0     pty 6
 24 char  25         0         db16aaa0 0     pty 7
 25 char  26         0         db163c10 0     ptr 0
 26 char  27         0         0        0     hbtcpip0
 27 char  28         0         0        0     rmx
 28 char  29         1         db1ac328 0     unfs
 29 char  30         2         db1f0ce8 0     nfssvc
 30 char  31         0         db1f10e8 0     nfs_cache
 31 char  32         2         db2ae0e8 0     lock
 32 char  33         0         db0b05ac 0     streams
 33 stdev 34         0         0        0     clone
 34 stdev 35         0         0        0     strlog
 35 stdev 36         0         0        0     spipe
 36 char  37         0         0        0     tli
 37 stdev 38         0         0        0     tcp
 38 stdev 39         0         0        0     udp
 39 stdev 40         0         0        0     ip
 40 stdev 41         0         0        0     echo
 41 stdev 42         0         0        0     mux
 42 stdev 43         0         0        0     otomux
 43 char  44         0         0        0     Lynx Filesystem
 44 char  45         0         0        0     ISO9660 Filesystem
 45 char  46         0         db33bbd8 0     klog
 46 char  47         1         db33cc00 0     dpram
 0  block 6          3         db161870 0     HD 0-1
 1  block 8          0         db163918 0     Floppy 0-3
 2  block 10         0         (no dev) 0     SIM1522 SCSI
 3  block 12         0         (no dev) 0     SIM1542 SCSI
 4  block 14         0         (no dev) 0     SIM1742 SCSI
 5  block 16         0         (no dev) 0     SIM2742 SCSI
 6  block 18         0         (no dev) 0     SIM2940 SCSI
 7  block 21         0         db163e58 0     scsi_hd
 8  block 24         0         (no dev) 0     HDS 2-3
```

In another machine where I have the ethernet card working is that the rmx line is the following:

```
 27 char  28         0         (no dev) 0     rmx
```

Well, and different addresses in other devices, but I think that is normal.

So, looks like device installation didn't detected my card, what can I do?

Hardware has been tested and it is working with another microsoft OS.

Cheers